# Unable to retrieve easdeviceID from managed devices via Graph API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, intune

I domain joined an iOS device and logged in successfully to Outlook native iOS app. When I query the "manageddevice" using GET request documented [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/intune_onboarding_manageddevice). It indicates that I my managementState is "managed" and managementAgent is "eas". However, I am unable to see the easDeviceId. Is there another end point that can pull this value?

[Response of GET manageddevice request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIi07.png)

Comment: The devicetype in your request result is shown as "desktop", which I think should be "mobile" instead. Additionally, how can you domain join a IOS device? Or did you mean work place join?

Comment: I did mean workplace join, my mistake. I used a link like this to join the iOS device. I do not know why it shows "desktop" instead of "mobile". https://technet.microsoft.com/windows-server-docs/identity/ad-fs/operations/walkthrough--workplace-join-with-an-ios-device

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the workplace join has nothing to do with EAS (Exchange ActiveSync). Workplace Join is mainly used for Conditional Access, Single Sign on, MFA, etc. However EAS is mainly used for providing limited mobile device management while the mobile devices are not enrolled in MDM at this moment. When you log in to the IOS native mail client or the outlook mobile app with a Exchange licensed user, the user device will connect to EAS service no matter the device is workplace joined or not.

Can you see this IOS device listed on the New Azure portal->Azure AD->Users and groups->select the user account used to workplace join->Devices? The workplace joined devices should list here.

If you are also using Intune and have set up Exchange Connection, the EAS managed devices should appear on the Intune Admin console.